# Coldfusion 2018 - sql server 2016 - Linked server to Oracle 12c - ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS error

Tags: coldfusion, oracle12c, sql-server-2016

We have 3 coldfusion servers. All of them have the same settings, as far as I can tell. The sql server connected has a linked oracle server, and when using OPENQUERY(), it sometimes throws this error on one of the servers. I think maybe it has to do with encoding, but nothing seems to be set incorrectly.

```
Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection.
```

This issue only occurs on 1 of the servers, and only sometimes. It has never thrown the error on the other two servers.

Here's what I've tried so far, without success. I also tried deleting and rebuilding the linked server connection to oracle.

Top of Page:

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

Before queries:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON;
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
```

Comment: Have you done any troubleshooting to analyse the nature of the queries that are giving you the issue? eg: logging the SQL of queries that fail, etc? I don't think the `cfprocessingdirective` thing is going to be relevant here. All that does is tell the CFML code compiler to use UTF-8 when compiling the code. That information is never going to get anywhere near the DB.

Comment: Take a look at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82416/stored-proc-getting-ansi-nulls-and-ansi-warnings-error-when-executed-by-applicat to see if it helps. You SET commands probably won't work because if you are using cfqueryparam, CF will compile it down to a stored procedure and these commands need to be before that. I would also just triple check each datasource config to make sure they all match. If only 1 server is doing this, something must be off with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I'm not positive what resolved the issue (we tried several solutions in the same day), I believe it was one of two things:

We had previously deleted and added linked server instance with ansi_nulls on as part of the query, but it didn't work. However, the linked server was recently rebooted, so possibly it required relinking then rebooting.

We also found a SQL server agent job that was running with ANSI_NULLS off as part of the command. This part of the job was removed. I would find it quite odd if this was the issue, as I wouldn't expect one query shutting it off to affect another query that explicitly had it on, but maybe it will help someone else who runs into the same issue troubleshoot.

Comment: Are you sure that changing the agent job didn't break B while fixing A?

Comment: I really can't be sure of that, no. I just put the answer because of all the things we tried, recreating the linked server instance was the first but it wasn't successful. We didn't think of looking for commands with `ANSI_NULLS OFF` until several days later, and this was coincidentally the first day the linked server was restarted since recreating the connection.

Comment: Again, not entirely sure what worked, but when I was looking at other solutions, no one else mentioned making sure there were not ANSI_NULL OFF commands running elsewhere, which sounds obvious in retrospect, but never occurred to anyone on our team, because no one thought such a query existed.